# Command aggregate failed: Remote error from mongot :: caused by :: \"origin\" must be a date, number, or geoPoint (from \"compound.should[1].near\")

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, isodate, bsondocument

I'm using MongoDB Atlas and creating search pipeline using C# dictionary object then serializing it to json and then parsing the json string to BsonDocument.

In $search stage I'm using near object in compound should with origin date for sorting.

[As you can see I'm creating an object for near in which my origin is DateTime.UtcNow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH64e.png)

[Here is my function which converts Dictionary objects to BsonDocument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItJic.png)

[This is my BsonDocument after converting Dictionary objects to Json and then converting to Bson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayrvG.png)

[Here I'm using it in agreegation pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFrbE.png)

The main problem is mongodb is not accepting C# DateTime as a date in origin.

Please guide me how can i give proper MongoDb date from my C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow. Maybe you need to convert your near origin parameter specifically with BsonDateTime prior to conversion of the entire object, like so:

`new BsonDateTime(origin)`

In the future it is easier for us to assist if you paste the code rather than the picture whenever possible.

Comment: I’ve tried what you’ve told me but still it is throwing same error.

You can see my code

var nearCreateDateObject = new NearClauseSearchModel
{
path = “CreatedDate”,
origin = new BsonDateTime(DateTime.Today.Date),
pivot = Convert.ToUInt64(“7776000000”),
score = GenericObject(“boost”, GenericObject(“value”, createDateScore))
};

and this is the final bson.
“near”:{
“path”:“CreatedDate”,
“origin”:“2021-04-17T19:00:00Z”,
“pivot”:“NumberLong(”“7776000000"”)",
“score”:{
“boost”:{
“value”:1
}
}
}

Comment: can you format with "`"? That makes it easier to read. Can you edit your original post with the code? It will make it easier to answer the question.

Comment: I've solved this error the way you told me & it works.
Thank you :)

Comment: can you upvote and accept the answer please? :)

Comment: Accepted and upvoted. :)